# How to keep all data (including images and references to other worksheets) when opening existing excel file

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an excel file with a pre-designed report that i want to automate by opening the excel file in python and adding data to the file but each time I do that, when I re-open the file it says the file is corrupt or "Find a problem with the content" and lost some tables and images.

```
    book = load_workbook('My_Workbook.xlsx')
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('My_Workbook.xlsx'), engine='openpyxl') 
    writer.book = book
    writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)

    df.to_excel(writer, "WSheet_name")
    writer.save()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is possible or not.  I have spent many hours trying to accomplish the same task.  What I now do is manage the data in a separate file and create a connection to that file with the excel file that has the reports and images.  In some cases I have written excel macros (called by python) to refresh the data.  I nearly always create the connection in power pivot as this makes adding new data much easier.
Try out this link [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/connect-to-a-flat-file-from-power-pivot-13b45182-7337-45f8-8567-e3968ca0ab4d) to learn how to connect a flat file to excel's PowerPivot.